# Storing mysql float values

Tags: mysql, floating-point

i'd like to store a number with double precision ([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] return value from objective-c)  in a mysql database.
The query seems to execute fine, but when i perform a select query, it returns 1.00000.
i have no clue why. i searched the web for clues, many came up but none solved my issue.

Can you guys help?

update query

```
update tblPurchased 
set 
    sync = '429568293.63687'
        and consumablecount = 0
where
    id = 2;
```

result from mysql workbench

```
22:52:09    update tblPurchased  set      sync = '429568293.63687'         and consumablecount = 0 where     id = 2 0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0  0.003 sec
```

or

```
22:58:25    update tblPurchased  set      sync = 429568293.63687         and consumablecount = 0 where     id = 2   0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0  0.003 sec
```

describe table

```
'sync', 'decimal(15,5)', 'NO', '', '0.00000', ''
```

result from select query

```
"id", "sync"
'2', '1.00000'
```

Comment: same result without the quotes. i have added comment from the mysql workbench tool

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: mysql wouldn't convert '425...' to just '1', however. it'd pull out as many digits from the start of the string it could. of course, mysql could be running in a strict sql mode, which is a whole different ballgame.

Comment: it is running in sql strict mode i believe. how can i tell?

Answer (score 2):

i need to learn how to write an update query ...

```
update tblPurchased 
set 
    sync = '429568293.63687'
        and consumablecount = 0 
where
    id = 2;
```

should be

```
update tblPurchased 
set 
    sync = 429568293.63687,
    consumablecount = 0
where
    id = 2;
```

Comment: Good catch about the wrong `AND` - another fine example of MySQL's sloppy data type checking